# How to get 2 level of directory?

Tags: c#, recursion, directory

I've a directory like this with some sub-directories :

```
root
    child-1
        child-1-1
            child-1-1-1
            ...
            child-1-1-n
        child-1-2
            child-1-2-1
            ...
            child-1-2-n
        ...
    child-2
        child-2-1
            child-2-1-1
            ...
            child-2-1-n
        child-2-2
            child-2-2-1
            ...
            child-2-2-n
    child-N
```

with this code:

```
var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\root");
var folders = dirInfo.GetDirectories().ToList();
foreach (var item in folders)
{
  Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

I just get 1st levels ;

```
child-1
child-2
child-3
....
child-n
```

now I wan to get list of `root` directory in 2 level :

```
child-1
    child-1-1
    child-1-2
child-2
    child-2-1
    child-2-2
...
```

I think it is possible with recursive function but I'm not sure about that.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: do you want to stop at the second level or go deeper?

Comment: yes I just want second levels of given directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should help you, just specify how deep you want to go in the main method

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.BufferHeight = 500;
            listDirec(@"c:\program files", 1, 2);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void listDirec(string path, int start, int end)
        {
            var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            var folders = dirInfo.GetDirectories().ToList();

            foreach (var item in folders)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft(start * 4, ' ') + item.Name);

                if (start < end)
                    listDirec(item.FullName, start + 1, end);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, one more thing : I wanna save parent folders and child folders for example in database, so I added this line of code instead printing on screen : `p.Add("".PadLeft(start * 4, ' '),item.Name);` `p` is a dictionary : `static Dictionary<string,string> p=new Dictionary<string, string>();` Is it good idea ? How can do that?